# c++ delete pointer to array of vector<int>

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

error in C++ delete pointer to vector array. 
see below code, I need to "new" array of vector with V(vertex num) size. 
btw, I have reason to use array and "new" here. Please don't workaround the question by not using "new"/"delete" operations.

```
class Graph
{
    int V;    // No. of vertices
    vector<int> *adj;    // An array of adjacency lists
public:
    Graph(int V);
    ~Graph();
...
};

// implementation
Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new vector<int>[V];
}

Graph::~Graph()
{
    int v; 
    for (v = 0; v < V; v++) {
        adj[v].clear();
    }
    delete adj; 
}


int main()
{
    int V=100;
    Graph g(V);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `delete[]`. And, what's the error?

Comment: Why on earth do you use a `vector<int> *`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong `delete`.  You need to use *array-delete* (and you also don't need to explicitly `clear()` the vectors):

```
Graph::~Graph()
{
    delete [] adj; 
}
```

Actually, you should be using another `std::vector`, or `std::unique_ptr`, rather than storing raw pointers.

You are also violating the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) by not supplying a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator.  If you were to do the following, you would have serious problems:

```
Graph f = g;
```

Storing the pointer as a `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>[]>` would make the above illegal (unless you made a copy constructor for it).  Storing a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` would make it behave correctly by default.

But since you're doing it manually, you'll need to either delete the copy constructor and copy assignment operator, or provide your own:

```
Graph::Graph( const Graph & other )
{
    V = other.V;
    adj = new vector<int>[V];
    std::copy( other.adj, other.adj + V, adj );
}

Graph& Graph::operator=( const Graph & other )
{
    if( this != &other )
    {
        Graph tmp( other );
        std::swap( V, tmp.V );
        std::swap( adj, other.adj );
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I tried "delete [] adj;" and it works. thanks for pointing out the other 2 issues. but the std:;copy & std::swap can not work on adj, I guess adj is a pointer to array, not a vector. I will try to use vector<vector<int>> instead.